# What's the most pythonic way to test if obj has any permission from a list

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-guardian

In both Django and Django Guardian it's simple to test if a user has a permission:

```
user.has_perm('app.can_eat_pizzas')
```

It's also easy to test if it has **all** permissions:

```
user.has_perms(('app.add_student', 'app.can_deliver_pizzas'))
```

What's the most pythonic way to test if the user has **any** permission?

I know I can just chain an if/or statement, but this feels cumbersome:

```
if user.has_perm('app.add_student') or user.has_perm('app.can_deliver_pizzas')
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
if any(user.has_perm(perm_name) for perm_name in permission_list):
    # rest of code
```

(Using `generator` inside `any()` has an additinal benefit that it stop checking elements of the list after first `True` evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

You can get user all permissions by using `user.user_permissions.all()` or along with `user.user_permissions.all().count()` by checking length of permission objects if length is greater than 0.

There is another way to check if a user has permissions in a list by that  `user.user_permissions.filter(pk__in=<list>)`

```
perms = Permission.objects.filter(pk__in=list)
perms.user.all()
```

Either you can get users based on permission or filter the by permissions list.

Hope it may help you